# Cell backcolor of active cell missing

Tags: c#, datagridview, backcolor

I have a datagridview in which I add a row after pressing Alt+T and make the first cell of the new row active. That cell is in fact the active cell at that point (F2 makes it editable), but it's backcolor is not changed while another cell in the row I was standing in when pressing Alt-T is highlighted (but not active). How can I make sure that the cell being active always has the backcolor it is supposed to have when active/selected?

Comment: Could you make it clearer on `while another cell in the row I was standing in when pressing Alt-T is highlighted`? Your problem is still unclear, no one can answer this until it's made clear.

Comment: If a cell is active/selected it's backcolor is dark blue (in my case). After adding the new row and selecting the first cell of the new row, that cell is not dark blue, but it is active, because if I press F2 it will be in edit mode. Another cell is dark blue, but it's not the active one.

Comment: How do you add new row? via the GUI or by code? Anyway that behavior is so strange, whenever you select a cell no matter via keyboard or mouse, the cell **would be the only CurrentCell** and should have BackColor of the selected cell.

Comment: By code. It's strange indeed, it looks like a bug.